# Replace Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am following example from Android doc example here: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

I was wondering if I want several different fragments on each page then what would be the best approach.

This is my MainActivity, as you can see I open new fragment class for each page position:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 4;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new MainActivity.ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 4 HeartsPageFragment objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new HeartsPageFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new DiamondsPageFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new ClubsPageFragment();
                case 3:
                    return new SpadesPageFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

This is one of the fragment classes, all four are almost same:

```
public class ClubsPageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.view_clubs, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I was wondering if it's best approach to have four different fragment classes for each page? I feel like this is repetition and bad, but I am not sure how I could fix this. It is lagging on my phone to when I switch between those. Any tips would be welcome.

Edit:

Here is the code for the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_suit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first_row_hearts">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_3"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_5"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/second_row_hearts"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_row_hearts"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_6" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_7" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView7"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_8" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_9" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/third_row_hearts"
        android:layout_below="@id/second_row_hearts"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_10" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_jack" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_queen" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_king"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fourth_row_hearts"
        android:layout_below="@+id/third_row_hearts"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/spades_ace"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is lagging? I've had a 13 page ViewPager before and no lag.

Comment: I have 13 images on each page, there are 4 pages total. And the layout has RelativeLayout which has 4 LinearLayouts inside it. Each image has size of 8kB.

Comment: Are you using an image loading library to display those images? If not, bitmaps consume memory quickly. At any point in the ViewPager, you have 39 images in memory.

Comment: No, i am not using any library. Which should I use?

Comment: Lots of people use Picasso or Glide. Not sure if it'll help

Comment: Is the size of 8kB per image ok?

Comment: Maybe. I don't really know what you are trying to do. You are 13 cards per suit. And you have one image per card. Each fragment shows all images. That's all fine, but what is the problem you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @cricket_007 I want to show all cards for each suit per page. So that will make 13 images per page and there will be total four pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you donot want to make different fragment classes study this auto generated code of tabbed activity android.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

LeftDrawerLayout mLeftDrawerLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }
    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 7 total pages.
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            case 3:
                return "SECTION 4";
            case 4:
                return "SECTION 5";
            case 5:
                return "SECTION 6";
            case 6:
                return "SECTION 7";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You just dumped the auto-generated code (most of which was already in the question). What are you trying to show here?

Comment: When your fragments have almost same data instead of creating new fragment classes you can use same class and create new instances of it that is what i meant (neX have used four different fragments instead of that he can use a method to create fragments dynamically)

Comment: How is that any different than this answer? `PlaceholderFragment.newInstance` calls `new PlaceholderFragment`, just different data within the same layout. Maybe OP wants different layouts.

Comment: He said that his fragments have almost same layout see his comment also        he can pass arguments to the different layouts